# What this 'at'/'@' symbol means in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-annotations, java-annotations

What do these annotations mean in this Kotlin code in android?

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
fun convertLongToDateString(systemTime: Long): String {
    return SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM-dd-yyyy' Time: 'HH:mm")
            .format(systemTime).toString()
}

@Entity(tablename = "daily_sleep_quality_table")
data class SleepNight(...)

    ....
    ....
```

Comment: i'm confused, you've tagged your own question with the tags `android-annotations` and `java-annotations` so you know that these _are_ annotations, what exactly is your question then ?

Comment: I just wanted to know what exactly do they do or mean in code. They look like Python decorators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ is a [Java annotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation), which also supported in Kotlin.

> @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")

**[@SuppressLint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/SuppressLint)** is an annotation used by the Android Lint tool. Lint will tell you whenever something in your code isn't optimal or may crash. By passing "SimpleDateFormat" there, you're suppressing all warnings that would tell you if you're using SimpleDateFormat in a wrong way.

> @Entity(tablename = "daily_sleep_quality_table")

**[@Entity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Entity)** is annotation used by SQLite to marks a class as an Entity. If your using that in your class, SQLite will identify your class as an Entity with the specified table name.

Answer (score 3):

check [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html)

@
- introduces an [annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#usage)
- introduces or references a [loop label](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#break-and-continue-labels)
- introduces or references a [lambda label](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) 
- references a ['this' expression from an outer scope](http://'this'%20expression%20from%20an%20outer%20scope) 
- references an [outer superclass](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#calling-the-superclass-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Those are [Java annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html) which kotlin supports

> Java annotations are 100% compatible with Kotlin

In your example [@Entity](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html)

> Specifies that the class is an entity. This annotation is applied to the entity class